# javascript - return variable value to use in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, undefined

Apparently I'm still very shaky on variable scope. Is there any way for `btn2` to get hold of values of 3 or 1 of `numHints` updated by radio buttons? (currently returns `undefined`).

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2y11rmt/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="btn">
<br>
<form id="Difficulty">
    <input checked="checked" type="radio" name="difficulty" id="easier">Easier
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="harder">Harder</form>
</div>
<br/>
<input id="btn2" type="button" value="btn2">
```

**JS:**

```
 var numHints;
 $('#btn').on('click', function () {
     var difficulty = $('input[name="difficulty"]:checked', '#Difficulty').attr('id');
     if (difficulty == "easier") {
         numHints = 3;
     } else {
         numHints = 1;
     }
     console.log(numHints);
     return numHints; // doesn't work
 });

 $('#btn2').on('click', function () {
     console.log(numHints); // undefined, need numHints available in here
 });
```

Comment: It works for me - http://plnkr.co/edit/tzFJlvdvVnGXOfGBDXpj?p=preview

Comment: The `return` line makes no sense in your code. What do you think it is doing?

Comment: SInce you're closing over that numHints variable, it's important where you're defining those two click handlers. As the code is written in the question (and nikhil's fiddle), numHints is in scope for both click handling functions.  Is this true in your actual codebase?

Comment: I don't get your logic there. Why are you expecting clicking on `#btn2` to get relevant value of radio checked (ya setting a variable but...)? Nothing in your code reflect this logic and your `return` statement doesn't make sense. Isn't it what you are looking for instead: http://jsfiddle.net/y2y11rmt/2/

Comment: I simplified (changed) my code to just address a variable scope problem and I oversimplified it. I now realize that it is a variable hoisting problem. My code tried to get hold of numHints before any value was set to it. Yes, the return makes no sense. (problem solved basically)

Answer (score 0):

It will work only if you click the `#btn` first, otherwise, the variable is undefined.
You could initialize it with a value:

```
var numHints = 3;
```

Also, your `return` doesn't make sense